# Class 'ZipArchive' not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I installed the php7-2-zip package in Linux, but I have:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zip Archive' not found

when I use this line:

```php
$archive = new ZipArchive();
```

Comment: Please share more details, and your debugging attempts

Answer (score 2):

This error means either  `ZipArchive` is not installed on your system or you are not using it correctly.

if    `ZipArchive` is installed already then enable it by adding below line in your php.ini file

`extension=zip.so`

then restart your server & use it like

```
$archive = new \ZipArchive();
```

or it is not installed then installed it using below command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

Comment: i used sudo apt-get install php-zip  but my problem not solve. should i install any zip archive in laravel and add in app.php ?

Comment: run this command in terminal `php -m` and check `ziparchieve` is there or not

Comment: yes i  use  this  *use ZipArchive;* in controller  and use back slash but not solved !

Comment: try to restart your apache server `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: my web server is nginx and i restarted it and php-fpm

Comment: thanks a lot . i add this line extension=zip.so in php.ini

Comment: Great! Please accpet the answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
sudo phpenmod zip
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

u need to use backslash `\` - `$archive = new \ZipArchive();`

Comment: This might be a good time to point out the `use` statement, or to explain how to verify that the missing backslash is the only way to get this error, or what else to look for.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it